# How to know which page is used to call a particular component?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a component name "personal-info" which is the subform of page_a and page_b.

```
// PAGE_A
.......
<div>
  <app-personal-info formControlName="personalInfo"></app-personal-info>
</div>
......


// PAGE_B
.......
<div>
  <app-personal-info formControlName="personalInfo"></app-personal-info>
</div>
......
```

How do I know from personal-info component that a call is being made from page_a OR page_b so that i can chance the behavior/appearance of personal-info based on the calling page.

Comment: You can pass a `Input` from your pages to component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way is pass an `Input` from pages

Like

```
<app-personal-info formControlName="personalInfo" [pageName]="'page1'"></app-personal-info>
```

And handle it in your component's TS file

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ActivatedRoute](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute) to check the current route. But most probably you don't want to make it dependent on the route or parent component, but just want to make it customizable - you can do this using the [@Input](https://angular.io/api/core/Input) decorator.

Just have in mind, that your `app-personal-info` component shouldn't care about parent component. Instead, the parent compnent's responsibility should be to pass correct customization values to `app-personal-info`, e.g.

```
<app-personal-info formControlName="personalInfo" apiEndpoint="page_b" color="#FFFFFF" size="large"></app-personal-info>
```

This makes it more readable and future proof (e.g. in case you want to add third subpage).